# Are "prime factorization" and "integer factorization" the same?

Tags: terminology, prime-factorization

Are "prime factorization" and "integer factorization" the same? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: Using all capital letters represents shouting and is quite rude - please don't do that again. Also, [what didn't you understand from the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)?

Comment: Sorry...I don't know I'm still new in this website...Yes I have search about it...I'm just confirming it, if the correct term is Prime Factorization or Prime Decomposition on what I am searching..

Comment: They are both correct short forms of the phrase "factorization of an integer into primes" (or many other equivalent phrases).

Answer (score 3):

The expressions: prime factorization, integer factorization, and prime decomposition are common "short forms" of saying "factorization of an integer into primes". (Indeed, if you search Wikipedia for "prime factorization" or "prime decomposition", both phrases "redirect" to the entry entitled "integer factorization".) We can always factor/decompose an integer $n>1$ into its prime factors: this can always be done, and it can be done uniquely. See the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

For a clearer understanding about integer factors, divisors, and factorization of an integer into primes, see these [Khan Academy video tutorials](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/factors-multiples/prime_factorization/v/prime-factorization).

Comment: Nice links ... +1

Comment: Nice observations...+1

Answer (score 1):

Prime factorization is factors in the form of prime numbers
e.g. 24 = 2 × 2 × 2 × 3 here only prime numbers are there  in the factors
in integer factorization factors need not be prime factors

### e.g 24 = 2 × 12 or 3 × 8 or 4 × 6